# Angular + Bootstrap Navbar Issue

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 4 and bootstrap 3.3.7.  The issue I have is that although the navbar collapses into a "hamburger" as expected, the hamburger is unresponsive to user clicks.  I found a non angular working example here

> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

but even when I replaced my nav element with that from the working example the copied navbar hamburger was unresponsive also.

Here's my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- index.html -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

Here's my html containing the copied navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class='container main-container' >
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What's your question exactly? can you provide a plunker?

Comment: I want the hamburger icon to be responsive, when I click it I'd like to see my other navigation items show/hide.  Getting close with answer below from Angela Pan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 4, the button should look something like this:

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

Notice the (click) part is new syntax for events, different from Angular 1+.

And instead of  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">`, try this: `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed" >`

In the nav.component.ts file, declare a variable called "isCollapsed" and set to true by default.

Install ng-bootstrap if you haven't done so.

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

In your app.module.ts file, you will need to `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` and add `NgbModule.forRoot()` in the imports section under NgModule.

In short, Angular 4 is using this functionality for the hamburger button to work properly. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

Comment: I made all the suggested changes and it's almost there.  The hamburger icon is different, it's not 3 horizontal bars and it is always present.  I was hoping only to see it when it was needed.  I'm much closer, thanks!

Comment: BTW, I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 not 4.

Comment: You can see the results here https://djangularphil.herokuapp.com/records

Comment: hi, the hamburger icon in my app only appears when the width gets small. And it is 3 horizontal bars. But I see that you solved your issues. Great!

Comment: Solved mostly except for the look of the hamburger icon and when its visible.  Are you using bootstrap 4?

Comment: yes, I'm using Bootstrap 4, but I don't know whether Bootstrap would be the reason though. What does your hamburger icon looks like? and it's always there?

Comment: see it here https://djangularphil.herokuapp.com/records (it's just to the right of My Record Collection  - it looks like a little white rectangular box

Comment: seems like "navbar toggler icon" is a Bootstrap 4 icon. Your 3 lines of <span> should still work. And it always appear because the positon. Try to still use the class names in your original code. Just edit the (click) and the [ngbCollapse] part. As you stretch the width, you can tell the position of the hamburger icon always stay there (stuck between the website name and the search field).

Comment: Awesome, perfect. Thank you Angela!

Comment: Thank, it works great. My final button element was: <button type="button" class='navbar-toggle' (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">    (Note "toggle instead of toggler) It puts the hamburger icon back on the right.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz solution was ... in the old Bootstrap 4 Alpha version. toggle is I believe Bootstrap 4 Beta

Comment: @PhilO - Did you manage to get this working for bootstrap 3.3.7? Just curious before I try implement it within my project, TIA

Comment: @Trebblez - I upgraded to 4.0.0 beta at that time to solve it